# internet connection check in a tab showing null pointer exception

Tags: android, tabs, nullpointerexception

I have tabactivity with 5 tabs and in one of the tabs I am trying to detect an internet connection and do some activity if the there is an internet connection..
the code i am using is

```
    // flag for Internet connection status
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

// Connection detector class
ConnectionDetector cd;

  submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                if (isInternetPresent) {
        // Internet Connection is Present
        // make HTTP requests
        Toast.makeText(ApplicationManagement.tabcontext, "Data Uploading to the Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




    } else {
        // Internet connection is not present
        // Ask user to connect to Internet
        Toast.makeText(ApplicationManagement.tabcontext, "Please check your internet connection and TRY AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
        }
    });
```

i an getting a NullPointerException at line `isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();`

and ConnectionDetector.java is:

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
}
```

I cant seem to figure out why is there a null pointer exception???
Is it because i am using Tabs because tabs create a lot of context issues???
Please help!

Comment: Well, if you're actually getting a nullpointer at the line you say and not somewhere inside ConnectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet() it means that 'cd' is null.

Comment: where did you initialise the variable cd?

Comment: +1 for a good description of the problem

Comment: thanks guys! I had not pass the context! how stupid of me!! anyways... problem solved!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget to initialize `cd` instance of `ConnectionDetector` . initialize it as before calling isConnectingToInternet() method :

```
cd=new ConnectionDetector(Your_Current_Activity.this);
isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
```

Comment: thanks ! I had not pass the context! how stupid of me!! anyways... problem solved!!

Answer (score 0):

yes you get the NPE becouse you forgett to create a new `ConnectionDetector`.
Try it again with that code:

```
ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way Create object of ConnectionDetector then use

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 ConnectionDetector cd=new ConnectionDetector(this);
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            if (isInternetPresent) {
    // Internet Connection is Present
    // make HTTP requests
    Toast.makeText(ApplicationManagement.tabcontext, "Data Uploading to the Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




}
```